# Dredd not killing main.go fix needed

Tags: go, dredd

I'm new to [this](https://dredd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) tool and looking for help with what I'm sure is a common issue.

As I [understand](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/pull/761) dredd isn't able to **kill processes** that it started, for me this is *main.go*.

My test feature is working great but the second time I obviously run into issues at the port is in use.

I've read most of the [articles](https://blog.apiary.io/2013/10/17/How-to-test-api-with-api-blueprint-and-dredd) and [guides](https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2015/01/28/dredd-api-testing-documentation/) out there but I'm not able to understand how to implement the necessary fix.

I tried creating script/test.sh

```
  #!/bin/sh
  go run main.go
  sleep 3
  PID=$!
  dredd apiary.apib http://localhost:5000/
  RESULT=$?
  kill -9 $PID
  exit $RESULT
```

and then running ./scripts/test.sh instead of dredd but its not working at all.

What is the best way to implement a fix for this that would also work on **circleCI**?

Comment: have you tried adding `defer server.Listener.Close()` to the end of the `main` func?

Comment: `main.go` is a source file, not a process or even an executable. how are you running your process?

Comment: I'm just running `go run main.go` thanks

Comment: With adding the `defer server.Listener.Close()` i get syntax error `srv.Listener undefined (type *http.Server has no field or method Listener)`

Comment: Try compiling the binary and running it directly (not sure what the defer would solve, since the process is being interrupted, plus defers don't even run after exiting via a signal).

Comment: will that work as i need to run the web server?

Comment: no your right, "Using Dredd with Go is slightly different to other languages, as a binary needs to be compiled for execution" https://dredd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hooks-go.html

Comment: still not sure how to implement though. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.

I had to delete the dredd.yml file and run

`$ go build`

then

`$ dredd apiary.apib http://127.0.0.1:5000 --server=./go-project --language=go`

But circleCI testing is **not working**, it just seems to ignore the circle.yml file and skips straight past it.